# Getting the list of days of the current week from DateTime.Now

Tags: c#

My paradoxical or perhaps trivial problem is to create me a list of the days in format DD - MM - YY from the date of today. Suppose we have today as " 11/04/2015 ". I want to create a list of datetime that starts exactly from Monday, 02.11.2015 to Sunday, 08.11.2015. How is this possible?

I thought initially :

```
DateTime today = new DateTime.Now;

int posDayOfWeek = (int)today.DayOfWeek;

if (posDayOfWeek < 7 && posDayOfWeek > 1)
{
    // And from there a black hole in my brain ....
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Always Monday to Sunday, or dependent on culture?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you always want Monday to Sunday, you just need something like:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
int currentDayOfWeek = (int) today.DayOfWeek;
DateTime sunday = today.AddDays(-currentDayOfWeek);
DateTime monday = sunday.AddDays(1);
// If we started on Sunday, we should actually have gone *back*
// 6 days instead of forward 1...
if (currentDayOfWeek == 0)
{
    monday = monday.AddDays(-7);
}
var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(days => monday.AddDays(days)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use this:

```
DayOfWeek[] days = { 
    DayOfWeek.Sunday, 
    DayOfWeek.Monday, 
    DayOfWeek.Tuesday, 
    DayOfWeek.Wednesday, 
    DayOfWeek.Thursday, 
    DayOfWeek.Friday, 
    DayOfWeek.Saturday };
```

It's simple.  It's clear.  And I've already typed it out for you.

Comment: Thats not what the op asked they asked for a list of days from the given date not the enum anyone knows that

Answer (score 1):

Easy way:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(x => (DayOfWeek)x).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching the web for something similar, I found this question/answer thread and expanded to create a sort order based on day of the week starting with yesterday:

```
//create a sort order that starts yesterday
DateTime orderStartDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
List<int> sortOrder = Enumerable.Range(0,7).Select(days => (int)orderStartDate.AddDays(days).DayOfWeek).ToList();

//sort collection using the index of the sortOrder
collection.AddRange(list.OrderBy(list  => sortOrder.FindIndex(days => day == list.TargetDay)));
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! Shortest and workfully!